# ng-click stops working after first click

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to create a modal popup toggle that's very similar to this post: http://adamalbrecht.com/2013/12/12/creating-a-simple-modal-dialog-directive-in-angular-js/

However, I'm running into issues because in my code, the ng-click code only runs once, and then it stops working the next time. I can bring up the modal dialog, but I can't duplicate it unless I refresh the page.

Here is the code:

/scripts/controllers/.navjs

```
'use strict';

app.controller('NavCtrl', function ($scope) {

  $scope.modalShown = false;
  $scope.toggleModal = function() {
    $scope.modalShown = !$scope.modalShown;
  };

 });
```

/views/nav.html

```
<div>
...
  <li><a ng-click="toggleModal()">Settings</a></li>
...
</div>
<modal show='modalShown' width='750px' height='60%'>
  <p>Modal Content Goes here<p>
</modal>
```

/scripts/directives/modal.js

```
'use strict';

app.directive('modal', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      show: '='
    },
    replace: true, // Replace with the template below
    transclude: true, // we want to insert custom content inside the directive
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      scope.dialogStyle = {};
      if (attrs.width) {
        scope.dialogStyle.width = attrs.width;
      }
      if (attrs.height) {
        scope.dialogStyle.height = attrs.height;
      }
      scope.hideModal = function() {
        scope.show = false;
      };
    },
    template: "<div class='ng-modal' ng-show='show'><div class='ng-modal-overlay' ng-click='hideModal()'></div><div class='ng-modal-dialog' ng-style='dialogStyle'><div class='ng-modal-close' ng-click='hideModal()'>X</div><div class='ng-modal-dialog-content' ng-transclude></div></div></div>"
  };
});
```

The toggleModal function seems to stop working after the first click. Any ideas?

**UPDATE**

This is what my index.html looks like:

```
<!-- Add your site or application content here -->
<div ng-controller='NavCtrl' ng-include="'views/nav.html'"></div>
<div ng-view="container" id="main-container"></div>
```

When I move the ng-controller='NavCtrl' below my ng-view then the toggle works, but then the nav bar occurs at the very bottom of the page...

Comment: Why do you call `hideModal()` and not `toggleModal()` or otherwise: does hideModal sets `$scope.modalShown = false;`, too?

Comment: are you able to create a fiddle?

Comment: Seems to be working here: http://plnkr.co/edit/lx2PcXsrSRWMFw8miTtL?p=preview

Comment: `ng-show='show'` I expected `true` or `false`, not `show`.  Maybe it should be `{show}`?

Comment: Thanks for the comment! updated my post with more content, @Jerrad i think the code should work as well, not sure why it isn't working now -- maybe my update can provide some more info?

Comment: please make a fiddle.

Comment: Did you ever figure out why this isn't working?

Answer (score 0):

Seems the problem is angular JS scope isolations. When you use ngInclude directive you have created isolated scope. And as you use just a bool variable it's not possible to change it from isolated scope. Necessary to use object.

Just use

```
 $scope.modalShown = {
    value: false
 }
```

in html

```
... show='modalShown.value' ...
```